# async await in virutal field in sequelize node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sequelize.js

Not able to get the s3 signed url for a virtual field in sequelize node.js

When trying to fetch file_uri (virtual field) returns empty object **{}**

**S3 Signed Url Function**

```
exports.getSignedUrl = async (path) => {
    const s3Client = new S3Client({
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        },
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    });

    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
        Key: path,
    });

    return await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 900 }); // 15 Minutes
};
```

**Model Class**

```
const { Model } = require("sequelize");

import { getSignedUrl } from "../helpers/s3-helper";

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class ProductImage extends Model {}

    ProductImage.init(
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: false,
            },
            uri: DataTypes.STRING(400),
            file_uri: {
                type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
                async get() {
                    return await getSignedUrl(this.uri);
                },
            }
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: "product_image",
            tableName: "product_image",
            timestamps: true,
        }
    );

    return ProductImage;
};
```

Comment: There is no hints about async getters/setters/virtual fields there: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/ They should be sync I suppose